# debug XHR in chrome browser

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

How to see the post content in chrome?

Comment: at that time, we cannot do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>One option would be to use a normal packet sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).</strike> It seems that chrome now supports directly sniffing XHR, see below.

Comment: Accepted or not, this answer seems to make more sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535462/debug-xhr-in-chrome-browser/1591333#1591333

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, the answerer can't shift the accepted answer, only the questioner :)

Comment: So essentially the comment is "you can't"

Answer (score 33):

Start up the Developer tools (`Shift+Ctrl+J` on Linux) and click `Enable Resource Tracking`.  The page will refresh.  Click on the Resources button, XHRs are colored yellow.  To see the post content simply click on the resource.  The POST content is in the Request Headers.  You can also filter out just the XHRs with the XHR button in the bar below the tabs.

Hope this helps,
d34dh0r53

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, Chrome 12, I had to right-click somewhere in the console window and tick XMLHttpRequest logging to enable this.

Answer (score 8):

## 2015 Update

Chrome version 43 now, go to `Settings > General > Console` and check the "**Log XMLHttpRequests**" option.

Update:
I wanted to see the XHR Object, but it seems I still can't do that despite the logging.

Answer (score 5):

In the **Javascript console** pane **right click** and tick the "**Log XMLHttpRequests**" option. Then in the developer tools section choose the network tab.

When you fire the Ajax request a new item will (sometimes delayed) **appear in the network tab**. Click on it to inspect it and then choose "**Headers**".

That will show you the post data you just sent.

Answer (score 4):

**2020 Update**

In the current version of Chrome (Google Chrome 81.0.4044.138) you can simply

- Open the developer tools
- Navigate to the console
- Click on the console settings (represented by the sprocket widget near the top right corner)
- Toggle on 'Log XMLHttpRequests'

Answer (score 0):

**2015 Update**

The latest chrome forces you to select the request (represented by a small blue dot) in the timeline. Use the slider hooks to zoom in to the time you sent the request after the page loaded in your browser. You will see the request(s) in the pane below the timeline(which was hidden in my case and I had to drag the dev console much deeper in to the page real estate). I'm guessing google added this so you could track events across time better.

Answer (score 0):

Add on: If you cannot see Fecth/xhr,JS,CSS etc option in the Network tab.

Then don't try checking into each setting , instead "RESTORE DEFAULTS AND RELOAD: ( bottom of the setting). The options will appear, later you can edit settings.

Hope it helps.